# html helper html.dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: drop-down-menu, helper

give me full demonstration of html.dropdownlist
how it is implimented?
how to set values in the list?
how to use it in .aspx and in controller file?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me have a try

There is SelectList class that you can use to create a list in the controller class (in the approriate controller action) as follows:

```
var items = new KeyValueList();
var item = new KeyValue() {Key = 1, Value = "Orange" };    
items.Add(item);
item = new KeyValue() {Key = 2, Value = "Apple" };    
items.Add(item);

var myList = new SelectList(items, "Key", "Value", selectedItemId);
```

The selectedItemId will be the value of an item's key.  Then add myList to the ViewData collection with a key that you can use to refer to it from the View. Like:

```
ViewData["FruitList"] = myList;
```

In the View, you can then use:

```
            <p>
              <label for="FruitList">Fruits:</label>
              <%= Html.DropDownList("FruitList") %>
            </p>
```

On postback to the controller action, the "Key" for the selected value is sent as part of formcollection or post parameters, and you can access the value using the "FruitList".

Comment: What namespace contains KeyValueList?